# NodeJS: How to remove duplicates from Array

Tags: arrays, node.js, duplicates

I have an array:

```
[
    1029,
    1008,
    1040,
    1019,
    1030,
    1009,
    1041,
    1020,
    1031,
    1010,
    1042,
    1021,
    1030,
    1008,
    1045,
    1019,
    1032,
    1009,
    1049,
    1022,
    1031,
    1010,
    1042,
    1021,
]
```

Now I want to remove all the duplicates from it. Is there any method in NodeJs which can directly do this.

Comment: This might be faster than other approaches

Comment: myArray.filter(function(item , index, arr){ return arr.indexOf(item)=== index}) please ignore my previous comment , read your question incorrectly.

Answer (score 77):

No, there is no built in method in node.js, however there are plenty of ways to do this in javascript. All you have to do is [look around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array), as this has already been answered.

```
uniqueArray = myArray.filter(function(elem, pos) {
    return myArray.indexOf(elem) == pos;
})
```

Comment: Thanks Mihai and Jurka. I was just wondering if there is any built in method to do this. Anyways you guys solved my problem.

Best Regards

Comment: @YoYoSatySingh It's better to go through `Set` in Node.js now. The browser support is also starting to get there.

Comment: shorter version:  `uniques = array.filter((x, i) => i === array.indexOf(x))`

Answer (score 48):

No there is no built in method to get from array unique methods, but you could look at library called lodash which has such great methods `_.uniq(array)`.

Also, propose alternative method as the Node.js has now support for Set's. Instead of using 3rd party module use a built-in alternative.

```
var array = [
    1029,
    1008,
    1040,
    1019,
    1030,
    1009,
    1041,
    1020,
    1031,
    1010,
    1042,
    1021,
    1030,
    1008,
    1045,
    1019,
    1032,
    1009,
    1049,
    1022,
    1031,
    1010,
    1042,
    1021,
];

var uSet = new Set(array);
console.log([...uSet]); // Back to array
```

Comment: exactly - as a oneliner in 2022: `Array.from(new Set(array))`